# Redish weapon wood [eevee]

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, procedural

I am making an rpg-7, but can't get the wood material right

This is what i want:
[image]

This is what i was able to make:
[image]

Node setup:
[image]

How can i improve, and also add this shiny look to it

Comment: it looks pretty good so far.  If you want it to look exactly like the image, you could increase the color brightness, and turn down the roughness for a better result

Comment: Hello :). [Here on Blendernation](https://www.blendernation.com/2017/10/20/procedural-cc-0-pbr-wood-shader/) are some free wood shaders for inspiration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could begin with this setup, a *Noise* plugged into a *ColorRamp*, glossiness, and a bit of *Bump*:

[image]